# How to find records with nil associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

These are obviously not my actual Models but they serve as an example. I have the following class definitions.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :opening
    has_one :opening_info, through: :opening
end

class Opening < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
    has_one :opening_info
end

class OpeningInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opening
    # OpeningInfo has a opening_date attribute in the DB
end
```

I want to find all movies that have a valid Opening, a valid OpeningInfo through that Opening, and that OpeningInfo has a opening_date that is not nil. By valid I mean it exists. I have tried several expressions using joins and includes but it complains of illegal sql statements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably work, when opening_infos is the table name:

```
Movie.joins(:opening_info).where.not(opening_infos: { opening_date: nil })
```

Comment: @sjagr Yes, that's why we use `where.not`.

Comment: I need to get more coffee. Sorry to bother!

Comment: Would you mind showing a good way to get the opposite result? I tried getting the id's from your solution and then doing a Rails.where(not in ids) but that was really slow.